# Regex to match either any quoted string or a specific unquoted string

Tags: regex, csv

I need to parse a CSV using regex and one particular column needs to either be a string in quotes or NULL (as a string not a null value).

I can get the column if it is in quotes using `\,("[^"]*")` but any attempt to fetch it if it's NULL instead is proving beyond me. I assumed it'd be something like `\,(("[^"]*")|(NULL))` but that's causing weird results.

To sum the problem up, it needs to match:

"Foo"

NULL

but not:

bar

*edit*

If I use the value "This is a string, include it", the match is rejected (it gets accepted with just `("[^"]*")` ). NULL gets accepted, but it doesn't return the string 'NULL' which isn't the behaviour I need)

Here's the full regex: as it appears in the code:

```
@fields = $line =~ /^
        (\d{0,10}+)
        \,(\d{0,10}+)
        \,([0-9\.]{0,6}+)
        \,([0-9\.]{0,6}+)
        \,([^,]*)
        \,([^,]*)       
        \,(\d*\.?\d*)
        \,(\d*\.?\d*)   
        \,([^,]*)
        \,([^,]*)
        \,([^,]*)
        \,([^,]*)
        \,([^,]*)
        \,(\w{3}+)
        \,(\w{3}+)
        \,([^,]*)
        \,([^,]*)
        \,(\w{0,10})
        \,(\d+)
        \,([^,]*)           
        \,(\d{1}+)
        \,(("[^"]*")|(NULL))
        \,([^,]*)   
        \,([^,]*)   
        $
    /xo;
```

Here's a sample line (sorry if it's nonsensical):

1111,111111,0,0,This is some text,1111.11,0.00,0.00,2014-03-14 11:11:1111.111,Text,2014-03-11 11:11:11.111,Text,Text,LLL,AAA,1900-01-01 00:00:00.000,1900-01-01 23:59:59.000,NULL,0,2014-03-11 11:00:11.111,1,NULL,1111111,NULL

Output:

1111
111111
0
0
This is some text
1111.11
0.00
0.00
2014-03-14 11:11:1111.111
Text
2014-03-11 11:11:11.111
Text
Text
LLL
AAA
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
1900-01-01 23:59:59.000
NULL
0
2014-03-11 11:00:11.111
1
NULL

NULL
1111111
NULL

It looks like its returning 3 values for the \,(("[^"]*")|(NULL)) match : NULL, an empty string and NULL when it should just return a single NULL.

If I enclose the important NULL (third from last value) in quotes I get the following output:

1111
111111
0
0
This is some text
1111.11
0.00
0.00
2014-03-14 11:11:1111.111
Text
2014-03-11 11:11:11.111
Text
Text
LLL
AAA
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
1900-01-01 23:59:59.000
NULL
0
2014-03-11 11:00:11.111
1
"NULL"
"NULL"

1111111
NULL

So that also outputs 3 values instead of the single "NULL" it should output

Comment: What is the specific problem you are facing? How is it not working.

Comment: The Column is typically one of two formats: "This is a string, it needs to be included" or NULL. I need it to reject strings that aren't enclosed in speech marks unless it's NULL (as a string not an actual null value). The method I tried above seems to just go haywire, randomly rejecting roughly 50% of rows (only a small number of rows will have not null values).

Comment: Why not use a csv parser?

Comment: I tried it online on regexpal, it works __fine__

Comment: Can you edit your question (not in the comments) to give example of inputs, some of your code and what it outputs?

Comment: The code handles lots of different custom data files and it's only in this particular case the file is a CSV and potentially in the future the file format may change in a way where as parser wouldn't accept it) so using regex now makes changes later easier.

Comment: so you just want to match anything inside double quotes and NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the this part of your regex:

```
(("[^"]*")|(NULL))
```

to:

```
("[^"]*"|NULL)
```

You were having 3 capture groups up there. First contained `("[^"]*")|(NULL)`, second contained `"[^"]*"` and third contained `NULL`, and if you had `NULL`, you would be having `NULL` in the first capture group, an empty second capture group and `NULL` in the third capture group.

With my suggestion, you should have only one capture group having either `"[^"]*"` or `NULL`.

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks. Turns out it could also be blank in addition to having NULL as text but I added a |\d{0} after the null to test for a blank value.